# Zend Auth & ACL usage without the MVC components

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl, authentication

I want to make use of Zend modules such as Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl on my custom php site. 
Are there any code examples that do not refer to the full use (MVC components) of the Zend framework that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to use Zend ACL separately.

> **EDIT** this if you can add another helpful link

The following links are useful -

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html

http://www.zendcasts.com/zend-acl-with-authentication-and-reflection/2009/06/ (video)

http://blog.davidjclarke.co.uk/database-driven-zend-acl-controlling-access-to-your-web-application.html